# Wifi stopped working without apparent reason

Tags: wifi, broadcom

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa in a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop. Wireless connection has been working for years in this laptop in different linux distros with proprietary Broadcom driver. I formated my computer 14 days ago, and wireless was working fine after that. I have been alternating between cabled and wireless connection. Yesterday, after disconnecting my cable connection, suddenly I could not use wireless anymore. The wifi networks are listed, but I cannot connect to them. I have confirmed (with other computer) that the network is working properly. I checked the packages that were installed or updated since last time wifi was working, and there were none.
My kernel version is

```
$ uname -a
Linux mycomputer 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:37:25 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my wireless card:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000b]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Here is my dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg | grep wl
[   11.216767] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   11.225409] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.476882] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4315 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
```

Here is the output of iwconfig:

```
$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"housenet"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 20:CF:30:C6:32:A5   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Here is ip output (I don't know why it has state DORMANT and mode DORMANT):

```
$ ip link show wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DORMANT mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:23:4d:a8:e4:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Also, rfkill seems to show no problem.

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I've tried changing the driver from bcmwl-kernel-source to firmware-b43-installer, reboot the computer, but the problem persists. Strangely, the same problem is now happening in the USB-live version of LM 17.3.

Comment: Check what I posted half an hour ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791287/wlan-can-see-networks-but-cant-connect-to-any
Can you connect to any network with another distro?

Comment: I don't have another distro on this machine, only Windows.

Comment: But does it work there? Because if it does that would indicate a non-hardware problem - if you read my own thread, I've tried using other distros, including a completely fresh, live USB and it still failed. For the life of me, I can't imagine how a non-hardware issue can appear like that in different distros, including one booting from a live USB

Comment: @DigitalDracula it could also be a driver issue, not necessarily hardware.

Comment: @DigitalDracula I've tried in the live-USB of LM 17.3 and the problem is also happening there.

Comment: If it's the same distro, esp. if it's one you D/l now, it could include some update bug. But I had the problem with an entirely different OS, which defies logic...

Comment: Yes, but when I first installed this same distro wireless was working just fine. I will try with another one, but I'm starting to think that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Yeah, though it'd be one heck of a coincidence for both of us to get it simultaneously! :P

Comment: What is your wireless card?

Comment: Atheros something

Answer (score 1):

I solved my similar issue, maybe this applies to you too.

It appears I had accidentally pressed Fn + F2, which in this Fujitsu Siemens turns off the wifi. And, surprise-surprise, it remembers the choice even after a shutdown.

Check to make sure there isn't a physical button or shortcut combo like mine which deactivates your wifi. Apparently this persists between reboots.

Comment: But in this case you shouldn't be seeing the networks, right?

Comment: Good question. Apparently you can. Maybe the shortcut blocks the card from connecting, but allows scanning.

Comment: On my version (v30 in Ubuntu 16.04) `iwconfig` also shows the TxPower. It says `off` when in airplane mode, and `13dBm` when enabled.

Comment: It is usually a physical cut-off switch, so persisting across reboots is expected behaviour.